# angularjs ng-options dictionary filter not empty

Tags: angularjs

```
<select ng-model="new_key" ng-change="evaluate($parent.$index, k, new_key)" ng-options="key as key+'('+value+')' for (key, value) in vars">
```

vars has 3 keys. one value is undefined. How to create select with only valid values?

[image]

Comment: do you have option tag inside of the select?

Comment: Please show data used

Comment: I ended up using this: 

`<select ng-model="new_key" ng-change="evaluate($parent.$index, k, new_key)" ng-options="key as key+'('+value+')' for (key, value) in non_null_vars()">`

and:

`$scope.non_null_vars = function(){
  res = {}
  for(key in $scope.vars){
   if(!isNaN($scope.vars[key]))
    res[key] = $scope.vars[key]
  }
  return res
 }`

Comment: @charlietfl {{vars|json}} returns {"acceleration of car in ms-2":5,"mass of car in gms":1000000,"result_of_formula_1":1000,"result_of_formula_2":null}

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add below filter in the controller

```
$scope.removeNull = function(itm) {
 if(itm.Value)return itm; else return;
};
```

and add this filter in the ng-options like

```
ng-options="key as key+'('+value+')' for (key, value) in vars | filter : removeNull"
```

[Remove Null](http://jsfiddle.net/8ugw3s3d/)

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check this out

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Your `ng-model` is undefined.

> **Solution:** set a default value for `ng-model="new_key"` in your js.

Comment: has nothing to do with `NaN` in the `value`

Comment: I am not talking about `NaN`, I am talking about `undefined`. They are 2 different things. Because `ng-model` is undefined, ng-options is trying to select one of the options and because there is no such option (undefined) it is putting `<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>` instead.
Play with this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SEjAztH7l7yt6WE3DBuI?p=preview) you will understand.